# Transformation Theorem & Piecewise Function

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X \sim \mathcal N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$ be a random variable. Define a new random variable $Y$ as:

$$
 Y = g(X) =
  \begin{cases}
   a(z+X) & \text{if } (z+X) \leq k \\
   ak + b(z+X-k)        & \text{if } (z+X) > k,
  \end{cases}
$$ 
where $a$, $b$, $k$, and $z$ are scalars.
I want to calculate the expected value of $E(Y)$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed. I guess I should apply the transformation theorem:

$$
E(Y) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dF_x(x)
$$

But I don't know hot to apply it to $g(X)$.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I added a "self-study" tag to your question. That way users will know you're specifically trying to teach yourself something and can provide more targeted help. Feel free to undo the change if you don't think the tag is appropriate.

Comment: No, the self-study tag is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't you simply split the integral up into $(-\infty,k-z]$ and $(k-z,\infty)$, which then simplifies $g$ in each instance?